# Imitate behaviour of OutputStreamWriter with TcpSendingMessageHandler

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-ip

We used the below piece of code for a Tcp server:

```java
try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port)) {
    while (true) {
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        new ServerThread(socket).start();
    }
}
```

and `ServerThread`:

```java
private class ServerThread extends Thread {

        private final Socket socket;

        private ServerThread(Socket socket) {
            this.socket = socket;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try (final InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
                 final OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())) {

                int bytesRead;
                char[] buffer = new char[1024];

                while ((bytesRead = reader.read(buffer)) != -1){
                    System.out.println(new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead));
                    writer.write(/* some char[] */);
                    writer.flush();
                }

                // ...
                socket.close();

            } catch (IOException exception){
                // ...
                socket.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

We recently switched to using Spring integration:

```java
        @Bean
        public TcpNetServerConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
            TcpNetServerConnectionFactory factory = new TcpNetServerConnectionFactory(9000);
            ByteArrayRawSerializer serializer = new ByteArrayRawSerializer();
            factory.setDeserializer(serializer);
            factory.setSerializer(serializer);
            return factory;
        }

        @Bean
        public TcpReceivingChannelAdapter channelAdapter(AbstractServerConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
            TcpReceivingChannelAdapter adapter = new TcpReceivingChannelAdapter();
            adapter.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
            adapter.setOutputChannel(messageChannel());
            return adapter;
        }

        @Bean
        @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "outputChannel")
        public TcpSendingMessageHandler messageHandler(AbstractServerConnectionFactory connectionFactory){
            final TcpSendingMessageHandler handler = new TcpSendingMessageHandler();
            handler.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
            return handler;
        }

        @Bean
        public MessageChannel messageChannel() {
            return new DirectChannel();
        }

        @Bean
        @Transformer(inputChannel = "messageChannel", outputChannel = "loggingChannel")
        public ObjectToStringTransformer loggingTransformer() {
            return new ObjectToStringTransformer();
        }

        @Bean
        @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "loggingChannel")
        public void log(String message) {
            System.out.println(message);
        }
```

with above configuration; we successfully receive messages and print them. When I access the Spring application with a Telnet client, I do get the messages on terminal, however, a client application (written with C++ with `WinSock2.h`) gets a timeout. What is different with the application and how do I imitate the behaviour of `OutputStreamWriter`s

```
writer.write(/* some char[] */);
writer.flush();
```

with `TcpSendingMessageHandler` for the `WinSock2.h` application?

Answer (score 0):

Did you read `ByteArrayRawSerializer` JavaDocs? Do you know that it doesn't close a `Socket` by itself as you do in your custom code after reading and writing?

you probably need to think about closing a `Connection` after using it.

See this option on the `ConnectionFactory`:

```
/**
 * If true, sockets created by this factory will be used once.
 * @param singleUse The singleUse to set.
 */
public void setSingleUse(boolean singleUse) {
```

Then `TcpSendingMessageHandler` will close it after sending a message into that `OutputStreamWriter`.

Comment: Hi Artem, did you see that closing of socket is practically unreachable unless the client sends an invalid message that is not deserializable in the custom code? It's basically unreachable and all I need is to flush after every write. I don't need to close the socket, I want to reuse it.

Comment: Yeah, got it! Thanks. Not sure then how your client understands messages delimiter... we need to send in the end of message some terminator, if you don’t close a socket after sending